# Вывод имени пользователя WP на отдельной странице

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне нужно вывести на отдельной странице имя пользователя, написал следующий код:

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
echo 'Имя пользователя: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';?>
```

Но данный код не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Нет такого свойства user_firstname у объекта WP_User. Есть

```
wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
```

или

```
wp_get_current_user()->user_nicename;
```

или

```
wp_get_current_user()->display_name;
```

Вот все свойства, которые имеет объект WP_User

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может быть, nickname?

Comment: И такого нет. Зато есть nicename. Приложил картинку к ответу.

Comment: Неожиданно, nicename) `user_nicename is url sanitized version of user_login`